# CSS corrupted and gone blank - How can i recover it. - (PC BSOD & Restarted)

Tags: css

My PC BSOD and restarted. When I got the BSOD I was editing a CSS file in dreamweaver.

Now, my CSS file is blank and the browser's cache is empty.

Is there any way to recover my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were working on a text file (css or otherwise) and it was never saved when the computer restarted (via BSOD or otherwise) it means the data is pretty much likely lost.

Some software will automatically save periodically but you've not mentioned any detail so I can't comment on if this would have happened for you.

**UPDATE**

Based upon your new comments, Dreamweaver does not have a built in autosave functionality. Therefore, your work will have been lost.

Comment: sorry brother. i was using Dreamweaver to edit CSS file